# how to set style in web view in android

Tags: android

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

mainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView web1;
    String st = " This is First Application";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        web1.loadData(st, "text/html", "UTF-8");

    }

}
```

i want to set Night mOde using style can u please tell me how to Implment it text should come in white and background of web view should come in black color

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: yes dear actully i am able to change syle of all thing like Textview ,Edittext box ,Button an all Except web View please help me how to Implment It

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), you'll see all the available properties for WebView controls. And since it basically inherits from [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), you can always reference all the available properties settable. 
So, to basically answer your question, set the background property with the **android:background** attribute. 
 Also, since you are basically displaying an HTML page, you can customize the content with **css**. 
 
Hope this helps.

Comment: I have create  style Theme.Blue in which text is coming white and Back ground is black now i want apply this style to web view can please tell me how to apply ?

Comment: The documentation doesn't provide a direct way of applying such styles; you can either set the background and text properties via the layout files, or programmatically attach it.

Comment: Ok Let me do and I ll tell You share Ur email id dear so that i ll mail If any query ?

Comment: you can reply on here; we all can help.